# Is implementing an OnAction() handler on a right-click action even possible?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is implementing an OnAction() handler on a right-click action even possible? This is for a DropDown object created programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [WindowBeforeRightClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837868.aspx)

```
Public WithEvents appWord as Word.Application 

Private Sub appWord_WindowBeforeRightClick _ 
 (ByVal Sel As Selection, Cancel As Boolean) 
 Dim intResponse As Integer 

 intResponse = MsgBox("Selection = " & Sel & vbLf & vbLf _ 
 & "Continue with operation on this selection?", _ 
 vbYesNo) 
 If intResponse = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```

Or [customizing the right-click menu](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_shortcut_menu.html)

I have not tried either.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I want to try either. I'm actually asking on behalf of a friend actually.